# How can I make the same step time?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to plot (c,a1)  with paramaters of when c=1,2,3,4...,298 .. But I have a problem. The plot in the result gives me only a point. I thing it takes only last value of c . How can I plot this while c is increasing and a1 changing with respect to c ?  Thanks!

[image]

---

This is the plot function

```
function fcnplot(z,t)
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('plot')
plot(z,t,'-or')
hold on;
```

And fcn function

```
function [a1,a2,a3,c1] = fcn(c)
%#codegen
c1=c;
[a1,a2,a3]=fff(c)
end
```

Comment: after all your questions, I asked myself do you actually really want to use Simulink? everything seems easier without. In this case just use the `scope` block to plot your results "live". In general I think you can do a lot of stuff without the custom "Matlab Function" blocks, which are quite slow in most cases

Comment: @thewaywewalk  . It is my term project so unfortunately I must do simulink to do this. I used scope bu the result is same. I thing the problem is that C not increase  in every loop , it gives me only final c value and graph that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [X-Y Graph](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/xygraph.html) block instead.

Comment: I used x-y graph block but result is same as mine.I thing the problem is that C not increase in every loop , it gives me only final c value and graph that

Comment: Have you tried plotting `c` on a normal scope block. If it's not increasing, then there's something wrong with the model, it's not a plotting issue at all.

Comment: Yes I tried that , all C values are tha last value . Its not increase as you said. Something wrong but I couldnt understand that

Comment: @DMD Can you show us how you have configured the switch block?